# 400 Error on RUN sequence, fine when I step through

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro worksheet that sorts and copies data. I've programmed a run button to step through my macros in the necessary order. It works perfectly when I run each macro individually in order, but when I try to automate with the RUN button it pops a 400 error. I receive the error when it tries to run `Sheet3.Copy2`

Here is my RUN macro:

```
Sub RUN()

    Call ButtonDel
    Call DataDel
    Call Sort1
    Call Sort2
    Call Sort6
    Call Sheet3.PrintNum2
    Call Sheet3.Copy2
    Call Sheet4.PrintNum6
    Call Sheet4.Copy6
    
End Sub
```

and here is the macro that's crashing:

```
Sub Copy2()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim VInSertNum As Variant
    xRow = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
        VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "J")
        If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
           Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "J")).Copy
           Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "J")).Select
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
           xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
        End If
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

I'm stumped!

Comment: In the VBA editor, put a breakpoint on the "xRow=1" line, and see if the code gets there. If it does, step through your code line by line. If it doesn't then you are in the murky world of "Error 400": google might be your friend. As an aside, it is better practice to store the value of ScreenUpdating in a Boolean variable, then use this to reset the updating when you are finished.

Comment: I was able to step through until this line of code:
`Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "J")).Select`
Hmmm. Narrowed it down....

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that you are running macros for multiple sheets, and not activating the one that throws the error.

There are some events in VBA that need to have the worksheet activated before running.

Try to do `sheet3.activate` right after declare the variables and it shall work.

but events in vba are not the best approach, if you just want the value from a range in another range just do:

```
Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "J")).value = Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "J")).value
```

Comment: The better answer would be "Don't Select"